# Property of Positive/Negative

Tags: parity

Is there a word for whether something has the property of being positive or negative such as "parity" for being odd or even?

Comment: This is easy to find on Google, just searching *"[property of being positive or negative mathematics](https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=gyNAWeizOLSk8wej9bHoBA&gws_rd=cr&fg=1#q=property+of+being+positive+or+negative+mathematics)"* works fine.

Answer (score 3):

The word you are looking for is "sign". For instance, we would say $-5$ has negative sign, and $5$ has positive sign. The sign function is defined to be $x \mapsto |x|/x$ for $x \ne 0$.